# catchError always gets called in HTTP unit testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, rxjs, jasmine

I have a service that makes a HTTP call and I am trying to write tests for it. The method in the service that I am trying to test looks like this

```
// my.service.ts

setUserAgreement(accept: boolean): Observable<any> {
  const data = { accept };

  return this.http.post<any>(this.url, data, this.getHttpHeader('1'))
    .pipe(
      tap(x => this.logHttp(x)),
      map(x => this.parseHttp(x)),
      catchError(this.handleErrorInternal('setUserAgreement'))
    );
}
```

My test file looks like this

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';

import { myService } from './my.service';

describe('myService', () => {
  let service;
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ HttpClientTestingModule ]
    });

    service = TestBed.get(myService);
    httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
  });

  describe(`#setUserAgreement`, () => {
    const mockResponse = 'Mock response';

    afterEach(() => {
      httpMock.verify();
    });

    it(`should not call handleErrorInternal when the call resolves successfully`, async(() => {
      spyOn(service, 'handleErrorInternal');
      service.setUserAgreement(true).subscribe(() => {
        expect(service.handleErrorInternal).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
      });

      const req = httpMock.expectOne(service.url);
      req.flush(mockResponse, { status: 200, statusText: 'OK' });
    }));
  });
});
```

However the test fails with the message `Error: Expected spy handleErrorInternal not to have been called.`

Can someone please help?

Comment: Please check if your `this.logHttp(x)` and `this.parseHttp(x)` methods are throwing any exception when test runs? If yes, then make sure these methods do not throw any exception.

Comment: You should be specifying your service in the providers array to TestBed.  After the imports array, put a comma, then a new line with `providers: [myService]`

Comment: @user2216584 Thanks for your reply. I commented out those lines for the service but the test is still failing.

Comment: @dmcgrandle Thanks for your reply. I added the service to the providers (I surprised it was building without it). The issue is still there though.

Comment: Hmmm.  Change your spy to `and.callFake`, giving it a function that will console log the error being sent.  That should give you a clue as to where it is coming from... also, receive the response within the subscribe (you are currently ignoring what is being returned) and console.log it as well to be sure it is what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue, it looks like it was caused by this line

```
catchError(this.handleErrorInternal('setUserAgreement'))
```

Doing something like this fixed the behaviour

```
catchError(x => {
  this.handleErrorInternal('setUserAgreement');
  // return an observable here
})
```